# "on a project" vs "in a project"

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct form?

> I'd like to try CoolStuff 2.0 **on** a project

or

> I'd like to try CoolStuff 2.0 **in** a project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that it's a difference of emphasis - albeit subtle. When you use something *on* a project, the thing that you're using isn't really part of the project. It's used to help effect the project. On the other hand, if you use something *in* a project, it's integral to the project - part of the project itself. For example, a tool would be used *on* a project whereas a building material would be used *in* a project.

So, I think that it's a matter of what you're trying to indicate exactly. It's a subtle difference though.

And `to try` in this case would effectively be the same as `to use` as far as usage goes. So, if CoolStuff 2.0 is a tool, then you'd say "I'd like to try CoolStuff 2.0 **on** a project." Whereas if CoolStuff 2.0 is something that actually makes up the project, then you'd say "I'd like to try CoolStuff 2.0 **in** a project."

Answer (score 7):

I would say that it depends on the nature of "CoolStuff 2.0".  If CoolStuff is a package that you will be using to manage your project, or to assist in the creation and development of your project (for example, if your project is writing software and CoolStuff is an editor), then "on" is preferred.

But if CoolStuff is something (or does something) that you will be incorporating as part of your output (for example, if your project is writing software and CoolStuff is a library of software utility routines), then "in" is preferred.

Comment: Good answer. I accepted Jonathan's because it was slightly more thorough, but I upvoted both.