# "In this project" or "At this project"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

"In this project" or "At this project" or "On this project".

I have a question about which of the sentences is correct, maybe none of them is correct.
For example I am trying to speak about a project I have worked, and so I say

"(In,At,On) this project i dealt with an algorithm which ..."
or

"(In,At,On) this project i implement a code to calculate ..."

Comment: Please add a complete sentence of where you wish to use these phrases. That will help other SEians to come up with a definite answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["on a project" vs "in a project"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/on-a-project-vs-in-a-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should say "**In** this project, I implemente**d** a code to calculate ..."/"**In** this project, I worked on implementing a code to calculate ...". You work **on** something **in** a project.

Alternatively you can say, "While working **on** this project, I implemented a code to calculate ...".